# Customizing ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, customization

I have added a `ScrollView` for my android app in the layout file. I have also created a `class MyScrollView extends ScrollView` to implement some custom behaviour. But when I cast the ScrollView as -

```
MyScrollView msv = (MyScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
```

It raises an error saying that ScrollView cannot be cast to MyScrollView. How do I use my custom implementation?

Edit:

Here is my implementation of MyScrollView -

```
class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private GestureDetector gd;
    private View.OnTouchListener tl;

    public MyScrollView() {
        super(ItemDetailFragment.this.getActivity());
    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        gd = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollListener());
        setFadingEdgeLength(10);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) && gd.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }


    class YScrollListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return (Math.abs(distanceY) > 2 * Math.abs(distanceX));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the `MyScrollView` in the xml layout, instead of a standard `ScrollView`, e.g.

```
<com.your.app.MyScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/theScrollView"
    ... >
```

Make sure that your class has the standard constructors.

Comment: Now it gives an error in inflating the layout. I have added my source class in the question. Please have a look and tell what I am missing.

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet This is an inner class? Then it won't work, you must move it to a standalone class. And make sure you implement all three constructors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, why does it not work  for inner classes?

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet Inner (non-static) classes cannot be instantiated without an instance of the outer class, and the LayoutInflater doesn't know what activity you're inflating for.